# What is the solution of the second order differential equation $x'' = -\frac{\frac km}x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know we have straightforward solution if $x'' = -(k/m) x$ which is the simple harmonic equation. But, I don't know how to solve $x'' = -(k/m)/x$.

Comment: This doesn't have a solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by $x'$.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $x'$ and integrating both sides, $\frac{1}{2}x'^2 = -\frac{k}{m} ln(x)$. But, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
x''=-A/x \rightarrow \frac{dx'}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=x'\frac{dx'}{dx}=-A/x\rightarrow x'dx'=-A/xdx\rightarrow 1/2x'^2=-A\ln x+K
$$
$$
x'=\sqrt{-2A\ln x+2K}=dx/dt\rightarrow \int dt = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-2A\ln x+2K}}=\frac{-\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2A}}e^{K/A} \mbox{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{K - A \ln x}{A}}\right)
$$
where $A=k/m$