# What is the solution of the second order differential equation $x'' = -(k log(x))/(m x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I asked similar question before:

[What is the solution of the second order differential equation $x'' = -\frac{\frac km}x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507003/what-is-the-solution-of-the-second-order-differential-equation-x-frac-fr)

but I could not solve this question with the same method. Note that here there is an additional $log(x)$ term.

My attempt: let $x = \exp(y)$ then $\exp(2y)=-(k/m)y$.

Comment: Same idea as before:
$$ t = \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{A - \ln(x)^2}}$$
and the antiderivative seems not to be expressible in "closed form".

Comment: Thanks. I got this as well, but I was looking for a closed form solution.

Comment: Look all you want, but if it doesn't exist...

Comment: @kko : All antiderivatives of elementary functions do not have a standard closed form. This is the case with $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-\ln(x)^2}}$. But you can create a new special function, say $Kko(a,x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{a-\ln(t)^2}}$. Write a thesis on this function. Publish it. If it acquiers a large frame and if it comes to be often used in le math literature, this special function might enter the famous club of standard special functions. Then the closed form solution of your problem would be : $t=\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}Kko(A,x)+c_1$, and the inverse function for $x(t)$.

Comment: About the special functions created in order to express on closed form some not elementray integrals, see : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales